# Angular form validation not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am very new to Angular and trying to build signup form, after looking at tutorials I built this form, but its not validating.

Here is the code which I am using:

```
<div class="signup-cont cont form-container" ng-controller="signinSignUpController">
    <form id="login-form" name="signUpForm"  ng-submit="submitForm(signUpForm.$valid)" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : signUpForm.name.$invalid && !signUpForm.name.$pristine }">
            <input type="name" name="name" id="usr-name" class="inpt form-control" placeholder="Your name" ng-model="name" ng-required="true"/>
            <label class="control-label" for="name">Your name</label>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" ng-show="submitted && signUpForm.name.$invalid "></span>
            <p ng-show="submitted && signUpForm.name.$invalid" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error has-feedback' : submitted && signUpForm.email.$invalid}">
            <label class="control-label" for="email">Your email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="inpt form-control" ng-model="email" placeholder="Your email"  ng-required="true"/>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" ng-show="submitted && signUpForm.email.$invalid"></span>
            <p ng-show="submitted && signUpForm.email.$invalid" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error has-feedback' : submitted && signUpForm.password.$invalid}">
            <label class="control-label" for="password">Your password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="inpt form-control" ng-model="password" placeholder="Your Password" ng-required="true"/>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" ng-show="submitted && signUpForm.password.$invalid"></span>
            <p ng-show="submitted && signUpForm.password.$invalid" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="submit-wrap">
        <input type="submit" class="form-control submit-signup btn btn-black-border btn-default" ng-disabled="signUpForm.$invalid" value="SIGN UP"/>
        <a href="#" class="more">Terms and conditions</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Can someone please help me understand where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Post your js code. Also try to make it in a plunk.

Answer (score 0):

change ng-model="name" to ng-model="user.name", ng-model="password" to ng-model="user.password" and ng-model="email" to ng-model="user.email".

I have checked using plunker its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-show="submitted && signUpForm.name.$invalid"
```

What exactly is `submitted` here? If that is something in the controller, seems like it's set to false & failing the validation. Check out this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/sWVXbhp4tggCoqOjmZfZ) w/o the submitted flag.